# Notation for conditional random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

Suppose there is a random variable $X$ that is conditioned on an event $E\in\{0,1\}$.  I am looking for a proper way to express this.  For example, let random variable $Y=T+X$, where $T$ is another random variable (independent of $E$).  Can I write something like this (which seems rather strange)?

$$Y_0=T+X|E=0$$

Unfortunately, in my actual expression, $X$ has both a subscript and a superscript, so I can't use those without some awkwardness.  Any ideas?

Comment: I personally would write it like $T + (X \mid E = 0)$.

Comment: I suppose that, since $T$ is independent of $E$, one has $$(T+X)|E \equiv T+(X|E)$$